# how to send status code as response for Unauthorized requests to WCF rest service

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-401

I am trying to develop a WCF rest servie which needs authorization using custom attribute.

I want to send the response as 401 status code if the authorization key is not valid in custom attribute which implements IOperationBehavior and IParameterInspector.

can any one tell me how to send the 401 status code as response from the custom attribute.

Here is the implementation

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : Attribute,IOperationBehavior,
IParameterInspector
{

 #region IOperationBehavior Members 

 public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
 {
  dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
 }  
 #endregion

 #region IParameterInspector Members

 public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
 {          

  string publicKey =
  WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Header["Authorization"];

   if (publicKey == "592F2D7E-5E9C-400D-B0AE-1C2603C34137")
   {

   } 
   else
   {
    // Here i would like to send the response back to client 
     with the status code       
   }

 }

 return null;

}

 #endregion

}


[Authorization]
public bool signin(string username, string password)
{
}
```

Comment: I am looking at the ways to end the request  and send empty response with the status code back to client from custom attribute itself. Is there any way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WCF Rest Starter kit you can also do:

```
throw new Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebProtocolException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "message", ex);
```

That method has some more overloads if you need.

Comment: I am using framework 3.5 and I tried WebProtocolException. Then i got the error exception is not handled by the user. Also in the client side i got the status code as the 500 Internal Server Error.Is there a way to end the request and send response with 401 status code in custom attribute by using 3.5 framework.

Comment: I'm also using the 3.5 Framework and have no problems with that. You sould maybe not throw it from IOperationBehavior. For checking authentication I just implemended RequestInterceptor from WCF REST Starter kit.

Comment: Hi Thomas,I wont be able to use the RequestInterceptor since i am using WebScriptServiceHostFactory. Is there an alternative with which i can achieve the same.

Comment: Since I am using Framework 3.5. I used the WebProtocolException and IErrorHandler to send the Status Code for rest response in POX and Json formats.

Answer (score 2):

Throw a WebFormatException

```
throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Comment: I am using framework 3.5 and I tried WebProtocolException. Then i got the error exception is not handled by the user. Also in the client side i got the status code as the 500 Internal Server Error.Is there a way to end the request and send response with 401 status code in custom attribute by using 3.5 framework.

Comment: You can try setting the WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode to unauthorized and throw a FaultException

Comment: I tried throwing the FaultException but got back the error "exception is not handled by the user". Is there a way i can handle this exception and send the status code back to client.

Comment: unfortunately the status code that is returned is still 500 (even with WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode or HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401), only the message inside says 401

Answer (score 0):

```
public string CreateError(int code ,string description)
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = code;
            Context.Response.StatusDescription = description;
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            return null;
        }
```

Then from your web service methods just use this to return errors example:

```
return CreateError(403, "Request denied by server");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `aspnetcompatibilityMode` cannot be enabled in your WCF services, then you can do as below.

You have to intercept the message and set the status code in ***`HttpResponseMessageProperty`*** in the wcf message. I use a ***`CustomErrorHandler`*** for doing that and it works fine.

---

```
public class CustomErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
              fault.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = new HttpResponseMessageProperty() 
              { 
                    StatusCode = statusCode 
              };
        }
    }
```

---

Below code is for injecting CustomErrorHandler into the ***`ServiceBehavior`***.

```
public class CustomServiceBehaviour : IServiceBehavior
{
    ... other IServiceBehavior methods

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new CustomErrorHandler());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in web.config use the serviceBehavior

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="CustomServiceBehavior" type="MyNamespace.CustomServiceBehavior, MyAssembly" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
                <CustomServiceBehavior />
            </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior" name="SomeService">
        <endpoint ..../>
    </service>
</system.serviceModel>
```